# Registry Symbolic Link between different hives

Tags: c++, winapi

Can anyone explain why I can successfully create this registry symbolic link (using Win32 or Native API functions);

> Link => "hkey_local_machine\software\techinc"
>
> Target => "hkey_current_user\software\microsoft"

Yet, when I create this one, I get Error 5 (access denied);

> Link => "hkey_current_user\software\techinc"
>
> Target => "hkey_local_machine\software\microsoft"

I tried adding additional "security descriptors" as well, but it seems as though this is a hard Windows registry limitation.

I'm currently using C++, but I am reading similar issues with other languages. Unfortunately, I have scoured the web and found NIL.

What reinforces my theory that this is a hard limit, is that I can create this link without any errors;

> Link => "hkey_current_user\software\techinc"
>
> Target => "hkey_current_user\software\microsoft"

If someone could verify, that would be appreciated. Or maybe there is some "special" permissions, that I haven't tried yet, which are required to link between different hives.

Comment: link really is create without error. but you can not open keys via this link due access denied error

Comment: Exactly, everything looks good, up until you try do open the link. I can't find what "special" permissions these links are suppose to have. They are different from the "normal" links.

Comment: this is only for cross-hive links

Comment: What would the security permissions be for cross linked hives?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is not possible from a security reasons.
According to [MS10-021](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/security-updates/securitybulletins/2010/ms10-021), they mentioned that after CVE-2010-0237, they installed an update that:

> The update addresses this vulnerability by correctly blocking the
> traversal of symbolic links from untrusted to trusted hives.

It was also mentioned by James Forshaw in [his blog](https://googleprojectzero.blogspot.com/2015/08/windows-10hh-symbolic-link-mitigations.html):

> The fact that a low privilege process can create these types of
> symbolic links has been abused before (see MS10-020) which removed the
> ability to create symbolic links between a untrusted registry hive
> such as the current user’s hive and trusted system hive, but it didn’t
> do anything to block the sandbox case where the symbolic link attacks
> the same user’s hive at different privilege levels.

Answer (score -1):

My guess is that this is something to do with registry key redirection.  HKCU/Software is redirected; HKLM/Software is shared.

So (hand-wave) if you're operating in a redirected key, you can't link to a shared key since it's in a different physical hive.

Maybe.

This all hinges on you running a 32-bit program on 64-bit Windows.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/WinProg64/shared-registry-keys#redirected-shared-and-reflected-keys-under-wow64

Comment: Good suggestion, but using "hkey_users\<AdminSID>" instead of "hkey_current_user" has the same results, access denied. Also, I am using a 64 bit application on Windows 7 x64 OS. There must be some special, undocumented privileges needed (higher than Admin) or this is just not possible. I've tried a lot of privilege variations, but none of them allow access to the linked key. The funny thing is, is that the linked key is successfully created and the value of "SymbolicLinkValue" is successfully written to the key, it is just under some unknown privilege?

Comment: Someone over at Cplusplus.com mentioned that this issue might be due to the fact that "hkey_local_machine" has a higher security privilege than "hkey_current_user". I've tried reassigning registry key privileges, but must not have had the correct permissions set. Does anyone know how to read the security descriptors of one key and apply them to another key? I am very sorry for double posting this question on another site, but I really need to figure this one out for a school project and I'm at a dead end so far (with trust me, a lot of web search time behind me).

Comment: Another limitation I just found, creating a registry symbolic link for this; hkey_users\<AdminSID> and hkey_users\<a pre-loaded registry hive>, doesn't work either (throws an error 5 - access denied error). And this is within the same hive (I believe)?